# Can I append a child element to an element inside my master PHP page without JavaScript?

Tags: php, html

On my website, I have a `master.php`, which has the basic layout of my site. I also have another PHP file, in which I write `include('master.php');`.

Is it possible to create a child element to one that is created inside `master.php` using HTML? (e.g. I have an empty navbar in `master.php` on which I'd like to append a child div that is only available in `index.php`).

I understand that this can be achieved using JavaScript's `var.appendChild()`, but I'd rather not manually append each element that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so. So as per your example, you can use the below approach for your `index.php` file:

Filename: `index.php`

```
<?php
$navbarCollection = ['First Element','Second Element'];
include('master.php');
```

And you `master.php` file can have below code:

```
<navbar>
<?php if (count($navbarCollection)> 0) { 
  foreach($navbarCollection as $menuItem) { ?>
   <a class="nav-link" href="#"><?php echo $menuItem; ?></a>
} }?>
</navbar>
```

Basically you can use variables from `index.php` file inside `master.php` but they should be declared before including master file.

Hopefully it will save a bit time for you, cheers!!